# urg_node vs hokuyo_node

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, urg-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and what I want to do is create maps for my robot with hokuyo lidar range sensors.
I installed urg_node and hokuyo_node on my precise Hydro distribution of ROS.

I dont understand what the difference between these 2 nodes is and which one should I use. Is it true that urg_node is simply a new version of hokuyo_node and I shouldn't have installed hokuyo_node?

Also, some of the tutorials that explain how to use hokuyos only use hokuyo_node, so I'm a bit lost.
My hokuyo device keeps being assigned a device name /ttyACM1 instead of /ttyACM0 which is why urg_node no longer works and I can't get laser data in rviz.

Can anyone please HELP!!??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194022/urg_node-vs-hokuyo_node/) by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your device works with hokuyo_node, you can certainly keep using it. urg_node provides support for newer devices.

You can setup ubuntu to assign device names consistently using udev rules. [This](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node#Using_udev_to_Give_Hokuyos_Consistent_Device_Names) and [this](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node#Using_udev_to_Give_Hokuyos_Consistent_Device_Names) section shows an example rule for each node.

Create a root file as the root user, such as `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/50-hokuo.rules` (the number doesn't matter), and paste in one of the rules above. The rule will call a `getID` executable installed by the node into your ros installation, which pulls the serial number from the device, and then that is used for naming.

Once you've put the rule into the right place, unplug your device, call `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules; sudo service udev restart;`, and then plug your device back in. Now if you `ls -l | grep hokuyo` you should see the device name with the serial number appended.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2014-10-02**:
Thank you for the answer, paulbovbel !